How to install python-gnome2-extras on noble
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat). I need the embedding Mozilla components (i.e. the web browser) of a package named mozembed. I tried to install mozembed, but not surprisingly the suggested python-gnome2-extras package does not exist. What is the new package name?

Where did you get mozembed from?

I have not got mozembed yet, it will be my first install.

It appears that the packages that provide the features of the python-gnome2-extras package have changed a lot and some of them are available in new packages. mozembed provides features such as embedding Mozilla components, web automation and rich text editing. Which of these features do you need? Do you need all of them?

I need embedding Mozilla components (i.e. the browser).

WebKit and GTK+ are modern libraries used in GNOME applications for embedding web content. I don't know if that would be a suitable replacement for mozembed in your use case.
